# iOS5 - Storyboard/Segues - Come back/Jump in UINavigationController to previous UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue

I'm working on an iOS5 iPhone project with Storyboard. I'm using an app based on UINavigationController and pushing some UIViewControllers. I want to know what is the best approach to jump back with more than 1 back level to a previous UIViewController. Here a more detailed explanation:

```
(All is managed with a UINavigationController)
RootController is ViewController1
I push ViewController2
From ViewController2, I push ViewController3
I want to come back to UIViewController1 from a UIButton in UIViewController 3
```

Any suggestion for the best approach?

Thank you very much

SOLVED! using Delegate patter design and switching to UIViewController1.

Comment: No need to add solved to the question title. Simply answer your own question and mark it as the answer. This will help others that have a similar problem and come across your question.

Comment: Thank you James, I'm newbie and I cannot answer my own questions until 8 hours...Thanks anyway!

Comment: Any chance you can post your solution here?